# Dataflow jobs based on a template use the same temp directory

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We're testing running multiple Dataflow jobs from a template, with multiple jobs often running at the same time.

We're finding that the jobs are using the same temp directories, based on the timestamp of when the template was created, not when the job was run.

Here's an example temp directory:

`.temp-beam-2018-08-02_20-11-52-18/`

We see multiple jobs using these same temp directories in the bucket.

This appears to be the related line of code in Beam: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.java#L532.

Note the temp ID is an incrementing number, and the only other entropy in the temp directory is the timestamp, which we're finding is based on the template creation time, not job run time.

With multiple jobs using the same temp directories, could they interfering with each other's data? Is there a way around this?